# SAE to Mexico earlier than 1 month before my flight

Tags: visas, mexico

I plan to go to Mexico in about 1-2 months. I'll have to get Mexican electronic authorization (SAE).

There're cheap tickets 2 months from now.

SAE should be submitted, however, not earlier than a month before one's visit to Mexico -- this is a rule.

If one buys a ticket a few months in advance because they're cheap and a month before his flight he submits SAE and gets rejected -- this will be troublesome.

My question: is it strict that SAE should be submitted a month before one's trip to Mexico and not earlier than that?

How can I get away with buying tickets that are 2 months from now?

Comment: I don't see any connection between SAE application and buying a ticket. Why not buy ticket **now** and apply for SAE **in a month**? Or you think it will be easier to return ticket and get a refund in case of reject when doing that immediately after purchase rather than month later? Unlikely. Refund policy of most carriers doesn't take this into account

Comment: @Suncatcher. No. I think that why would I have to bother at all to return a ticket if SAE is rejected? I better apply for SAE first and if and only if it's approaved, I'll buy a ticket within a month period. How else can this be?

Comment: I believe that SAE is rarely rejected, it's purely formal procedure and you can safely buy a ticket. What concerns terms, I recently contacted Mexico consulate in my country and they confirmed 1 month period is a must, which seems dumb for me. The more in advance the better.

Comment: @Suncatcher  1 month is a must -- не ранее чем за месяц до поедки. за неделю-две до рейса -- можно, то есть

Comment: Yep. Exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

The [SAE](https://www.inm.gob.mx/sae/publico/en/solicitud.html) does not oblige you to travel. You may apply by giving tomorrow's date, and even if approved, not use it. You can then apply again later for your actual trip. (But be aware that even if you are approved today, you might not be approved next month. Though this is unlikely if you haven't done anything to annoy the Mexican government.)

Comment: do you imply that I should get one now and then a new one a month before my actual flight? will the 1st one get invalid after i'll have gotten the 2nd one?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the old one is invalid, if you don't use it!

Comment: today a ticket within a month period became cheap and I bought it. I'd previously specified 90 days in my SAE. Will this allow me to stay 180 days still?

Comment: @Katta, please do not repeat identical comments, they will only get deleted and are seen as noise. If people know the answer they will answer, if they do not know it, they will still not know it when you ask again.